# Don't understand this function signature: (const Boolean (*equals)(const Object object_1, const Object object_2))

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm trying to use an Arraylist library. The "create Arraylist" function is giving me trouble however, because the signature makes almost no sense to me. What would be a valid function call with that signature?

This is the full signature:
  Arraylist arraylist_create(const Boolean (*equals)(const Object object_1, const Object object_2))

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the function wants another function, that will be used to compare the objects in the arraylist.

Something like this:

```
const Boolean my_equals(const Object object_1, const Object object_2)
{
    // Should really cast the objects to the correct type for your values
    return object_1 == object_2;  // Replace with your own comparison
}

// In main()
Arraylist arraylist = arraylist_create(my_equals);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Arraylist arraylist_create(const Boolean (*equals)(const Object object_1, 
                                                   const Object object_2));
```

The argument of the function `arraylist_create` says that `equals` is a function pointer taking two parameters of type `const Object` and return type is `const Boolean`. The `arraylist_create` return type is `Arraylist`.

This example should help you -

```
 const Boolean foo( const Object obj1, const Object obj2 ){
      // ....
 }

 Arraylist temp = arraylist_create( &foo );
```

[More about function pointers.](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read it right to left for it to make sense.

This is a function pointer for a function taking 2 non-changing (const) objects of type Object and returning a non-changeable (const) object of type Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`arraylist_create` returns an `Arraylist` and takes as argument a pointer to a function returning `const Boolean` and taking as arguments two `const Object`s. So, first you need to specify (or obtain) a function compatible with the requirements of `equals` (presumably to compare the list elements), e.g.:

```
const Boolean myEquals(const Object object_1, const Object object_2) {
    return (Boolean which is true if object_1 is equal to object_2);
}
```

Then:

```
Arraylist list = arraylist_create(myEquals);
```